# Are both of these fences made by Lego?

Tags: part-identification

I have a group of 1 x 4 x 2 fences (Lego part 3633) in black, light bluish gray, and yellow.

However only a few of them say "Lego" on the bottom. These have hollow bottom pins (see picture below, right side).  The others do not say Lego or have a part number. They have solid bottom pins (see picture below, left side).

Normally I can feel the difference between Lego and non-Lego parts. But the parts with the solid pins have a Lego feel. Also the yellow ones are the same shade of yellow as my Legos and not the shade of MegaBloks I have.

Is it possible these solid pin fences are really Lego? Or have I been fooled?

[image]

Comment: It might just be an older part mold, other plates used to have the solid cylinders. I also have 2 like that (but with 3 numbers on the bottom), although I can't be 100% sure of their authenticity.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the pins on the bottom, as some part's design get a little refresh from time to time. Both cases were present in various LEGO bricks. My concern is about lack of LEGO identification and part number. The oldest fence I have is from 1995 and it is similar to the right one (LEGO logo + part number). However these fences were available since 1977, so there could have been different molds without any designation at the time. It is not possible to confirm the identity without comparing with the same item from very old set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got some of the left-hand side version with the solid pins and no markings in red.
They are most definitely original Lego as I never owned any non-Lego parts.
I'm fairly certain they came with the 1978 firetruck set nr. 620.

Comment: Tonny just to confirm you're saying you have fences like this that you know are Lego but do not say Lego on them anywhere?

Comment: @Scott Yes. They can't be anything else, because I ONLY have official Lego. And I have double-checked they came with set 620. It is the only set I have with these in red. I took a very close look at them, even with a magnifier. Not a single Lego logo or part-nbr to be seen. And with the closed pins as well.