# Which parts do not have the LEGO logo stamped on them?

Tags: part-identification, history

[image: LEGO logo on part]

As noted in [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9567/6174),
there are *very* few parts that do not have the LEGO logo included during manufacture.
But which parts are those?  Is there any semi-exhaustive list?  Does bricklink note this sort of thing anywhere?

I'm mostly curious from the perspective of someone who would be looking through bulk LEGO and trying to figure out whether they got real LEGO or clones.  Finding the logo is usually so reassuring.  I'm not worried about really ancient rare parts, but if you want to be that thorough don't let me discourage you.  Either way, some sort of list of parts that somebody should expect to be legitimate LEGO, but not worry about the lack of a logo, would be great.

Answer (score 6):

I certainly don't have a list, but I came across [Technic, Steering Arm with 4 Ball Joints with Black Wheel Hub (x872 / x873)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x873c01&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) part several times. I heard stories of Bricklink sellers being accused of shipping knock-off copy of this part (since it is a little pricey) due to absence of LEGO logo, despite them being legit items.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another example is this [watering can](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4325).  The green one we have is from Fabuland.  In fact several other Fabuland parts here also lack the logo - this [bench](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2041) for example.  I wonder if  in the 70s/early 80s, when Fabuland was designed, Lego were less concerned about putting their name on every last part.

Other parts I've seen without a logo tend to have some of the following features:

- no or hollow studs on top
- curved
- small
- translucent

This [electric light bulb cover](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4770) ticks all of those boxes

Comment: Could you specify which watering can you are talking about? URL leads to list of multiple items. The jug I have (in Trans-Light Blue) does have LEGO logo. It might be present due to part being used years later than it appeared in Fabuland sets. Does any of Fabuland parts you've mentioned have "Fabuland" text on them?

Comment: @Alex I've fixed the link.  I don't recall anything marked Fabuland on the part.  My daughter inherited her Fabuland  from her mum, and they weren't new when she got them.  Because of her age they are likely to be rather early sets.  You're right; the jug does have a logo so I've fixed that too.  I haven't checked everything but spot-checking a few Fabuland parts shows Lego logos on most, and no Fabuland logs - but then very few parts were exclusively Fabuland

Answer (score 6):

[Are both of these fences made by Lego?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/are-both-of-these-fences-made-by-lego/14597#14597)
This is another example. This fence piece came in logo and non-logo versions in the 1970's.

Answer (score 4):

The [Plant, Tree Palm Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2566&name=Plant,%20Tree%20Palm%20Top&category=%5BPlant,%20Tree%5D#T=C) part has had revisions where it was not marked with the LEGO logo, as we have learned in [this QA thread](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/13217/3631).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- I have looked at part [#4168 "Support 1 x 16 Lattice (Train Signal Mast)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4168&idColor=1) from my both harbour seaports (year 1991) and have neither found a part number nor a brand printed on them, although being original.
- For part [#2383 "Electric, Light 1 1/8 x 2 x 1 2/3 Cabinet with Lamp Holes (Sign Back) with Milky White Electric, Light 2 x 2 Clip-On Plate with Fire Logo Pattern"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2383c08) the clip-on part with a firefighter logo neither contains a part nor a brand.
- I can also confirm that part [#4773 "Electric, Light Bulb Cover (Colored Globe)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4773) don't have anything printed either (as in set [#6430 "
  Night Patroller"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6430-1) I own).

Answer (score 2):

The chrome gold rings for the Lotr and Hobbit sets don't seem to have any logo or text either

Answer (score 1):

The [maxifigure heads](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=685px1) from the 70s/early 80s don't have a logo anywhere, even though they have a solid stud on the head and two more solid studs for the ears. The hair and hat pieces don't have a logo either, just a number on the underside in the middle.

[image: maxifigure head] [image: maxifigure hair]

I found several more examples of no logos in my minifigure accessories collection:

[Popsicle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30222&name=Ice%20Pop%20(Freezer%20/%20Lollipop%20/%20Lolly%20/%20Pole%20/%20Popsicle%20/%20Stick)&category=%5BFood%20&%20Drink%5D) (no text anywhere)

[image: popsicle]

[Microphone](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=90370&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Microphone&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D) (number on the end of the pole)

[image: microphone]

[Fairy Wand](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6124&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Magic%20Wand&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D) (no text anywhere)

[image: fairy wand]

[Tomahawk](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13571c01&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Tomahawk%20with%20Flat%20Silver%20Blade&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D) (number on the pole just below the axe head, and on the top of the axe head, copyright logo on the base of the axe head)

[image: tomahawk]

[Key](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40359a&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Key&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D) (copyright logo on the handle)

[image: key]

I thought that maybe the key doesn't have the logo while the sprue does, but I checked from my collection and the sprue doesn't have a logo either, just numbers on the long flat bit.

All the minifig accessory examples I gave have a round pole area, so it looked like TLG doesn't like putting logos on curved parts. But then I found a [syringe](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87989&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Syringe&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D), and it has a logo on the round handle, even though all my examples without a logo also have a round handle!

[image: syringe]

Comment: I have both popsicles with no text, and popsicles with the logo on them. The logo is on the underside of the ice part (if you were holding it like it would be in real life).

Comment: @RSchulz Interesting! I checked my popsicle from the Yeti minifigure (series 11) and it does have the logo. It's hard to see though because it's so small.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find LEGO mark anywhere on the clear visors that spaceman wear. I first noticed when checking a red visor for Ninjago Mr E. Then looked at my extra visors: no matter the color none have LEGO or anything stamped on them.

Comment: That totally makes sense.  I wouldn't expect most tiny minifig accessories to have any space for a logo on them.

Answer (score 0):

Shields from the Black Falcons from around 1986 have no LEGO logo (as well as the head accessories).

[image: 3846pb055]

Answer (score -4):

food items, tiles, most minifigure weapons, accessories and hair.

Comment: Could you specify exact items?

Comment: You're wrong, almost all of these types of parts you mentioned are in my inventory and they have the Lego logo hidden on them. Just because they don't have studs doesn't mean that they're unable to put their logo.

Comment: I have multiple apples which look identical, except some have the Lego logo on the leaf connected to the stem, and some don't. Cherries also seem to not have the logo.