# Have you ever seen this color of Teddy Bear?

Tags: colour

I found a Teddy Bear in transparent red color, have anyone ever seen this before? I'm just not sure where can I buy this guy.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Neither [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=teddy%20bear&rpp=50&tab=P#T=P) nor [Brickset](https://brickset.com/parts?query=mini%20teddy%20bear) knows about such a piece (all teddy bear pieces of this mold with downward arms come in non-transparent colours and are printed), so it must be either a knock-off (very low value), or a test mold (very high value).

Comment: There have been reports of “rogue” employees running molding machines after hours to make custom prints of existing elements. This might be one of those.

Comment: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6186#T=C

Comment: @Valorum That one is a completely different mold.

Comment: @zovits - Indeed, and hence why I posted it as a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer above, check if it has the LEGO logo and the mould number molded on the bottom. Both should be clearly visible. If they are there, it's LEGO, if not, it isn't.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a list of all LEGO pieces that do _not_ have the LEGO name molded in them?

Comment: @Logarr [ask and you shall receive](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/15101/56) ;)