Verifying if "Hinge Vehicle Roof Holder 1 x 4 x 2 (4214)" in blue and white is LEGO
I found a blue and a white versions of what appears to be Hinge Vehicle Roof Holder 1 x 4 x 2 (4214) in a bulk LEGO donation but it does not have "LEGO" stamped anywhere on it. The white version has "5" and "01" stamped on the bottom. The blue version has "2" and "02" stamped on the bottom. Is this real LEGO or fake?

See also: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/15101/13403

I own that part in yellow (from sets 6658 and 6361, so I'm sure it's not a clone), and it has no "LEGO" markings, only a single "3" on the bottom:



As bricklink (the OP's own link) tells us it's known in blue but not in white, and this answer basically says that the lack of a "LEGO" stamp isn't unusual for that part, a possible answer to the OP might be that the white might very well be fake, but we have no indication that the blue is (I assume there are real LEGO parts in the donation, so we can't draw any conclusions from that).

@Henriksupportsthecommunity What? Bricklink lists 47 sets which are known to have this part in white.

Sorry about that, I got confused because "Dark Reader" (a browser plugin) for some reason changes the color sample for white.
